# Winforms: Multiple ComboBoxes with Unique Selections?

Tags: winforms, data-binding, combobox, c++-cli

I have several ComboBoxes in a WinForms application (written in C++/CLI) that I would like to bind to the same data source, a List of strings. Let's say for simplicity's sake that there are 2 ComboBoxes and the List has 4 elements, "Object 1", "Object 2", "Object 3", and "Object 4".

I'd like to have the selections work in the following way:

1. I select "Object 1" from ComboBox1.
2. I go to select other objects from ComboBox2. However, since "Object 1" has already been selected in ComboBox1, the only options I see in the drop-down menu from ComboBox2 are "Object 2", "Object 3", and "Object 4".

Basically, the selection in each ComboBox should be unique.

I think this can be done using CollectionView's in WPF, but how can I do this in WinForms?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try handle [BindingComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.bindingcomplete.aspx) event for each Combobox's binding and inside it set the other Comboboxes DataSource property(filter or whatever). Make sure you set [FormattingEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.formattingenabled.aspx) property of Binding to **true** to enable the BindingComplete event to be raised.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Jacob. I'll read up on BindingComplete and see how it works.